# Run/Debug Spring Boot application from Eclipse JEE Neon alone?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, gradle, spring-boot

I will keep this quick.

I am following an example from [the Spring documentation listed here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-mobile-web-content/#scratch). As I am using Gradle, I am able to run the application by using:

```
./gradlew bootRun.
```

Or I can build the JAR file using

```
./gradlew build
```

running the jar file

While all of this runs as instructed, that's kind of a pain. When I show this app to my boss, I would like to run it directly through the IDE. Whenever I right click the project (or even just the application class) as try to run it, the service doesn't work and just takes me to the following error:

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Sat May 27 22:32:23 EDT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Error resolving template "greeting", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

I googled this and can't seem to find a solution. I have tried creating a `src/main/resource/static/home.html`, but it did not work.

IS there anyone who can help me with this issue? Just for the record, the `application.properties` file currently reads as:

```
spring.mobile.devicedelegatingviewresolver.enabled: true
```

Comment: I've gotten it to work with maven and m2e, never gone back to work on gradle (or sbt). Do you have STS?

Comment: Download the gradle plugin for eclipse. Click your project `gradle -> refresh` and run it as a Spring boot application.

Comment: The error is complaining about a missing `greeting.html` so why would adding a `home.html` help? Also when using a Gradle project make sure you are using the Gradle plugins for Eclipse to import the project else things will not be added to the class path.

Comment: I already have the gradle plugin for eclipse. When I refresh it, it does nothing.

The reason I added a home.html was because another tutorial told me to add a src/main/static/home.html in order to start. Also, I have not imported anything as I build the project from scratch. 


Now it's not even working because changes are not made dynamically when I run this. So I have no idea what changes / things I tried yesterday that broke this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

So there were a couple things going on...

The main thing is that you have to actually open the project in package explorer, select the app class, right click and run as a java project. I was just clicking on the project, right clicking, and trying a bunch of different options (spring application, hello application, etc).

Comment: I think this is the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59948998/in-eclipse-a-spring-boot-webflux-websocket-application-runs-correctly-as-gradle